# ReactJS append dynamically columns into rows in image gallery

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I am trying to implement media galery in my web site with drag and drop mechanism in ReactJS. When user drops an image, I save it on the array and then I iterate through array and show the images dynamically. So I want to order the images into columns and rows with bootstrap, so I want each row to have 3 columns, but my problem is that I cant append dynamically an row and bind there the images (for example when i have 4 images, I want the 3 top to show in one row, and the last image to be shown in new Image). Any solution for this ? Here is my code example :

```
<div className="media-gallery">
                    {
                        this.state.files.map((file) => {
                            return (
                                <div key={file.name}>
                                    <div className="col-sm-4">
                                        <figure className= "gallery-thumb">
                                            <img src={file.preview} alt="thumb" className="ro-imgPreview" />
                                            <span className="icon icon-delete"><i className="fa fa-trash"></i></span>
                                        </figure>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            )
                        })
                    }
                </div>
```

This above is one component and then I called and renderd it below

```
<div>
                <div className="account-block">
                    <div className="add-title-tab">
                        <h3>Property media</h3>
                    </div>
                    <div className="add-tab-content">
                        <div className="add-tab-row">
                            <CLMediaGalery store={CLMediaStore} />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: Where is your `row` bootstrap class ?

Comment: You can pass `index` property in your `map` function, check for that and dynamically add className row to your div by doing something like : className={ index % 3 == 0 ? "row" : "' }

Answer (score 0):

You could try and compose the rows and columns in a separate function and call this within the render function for your media gallery div:

```
render(){
  const gallery = this.galleryGrid();
  return (
    <div className="media-gallery container">
      { gallery }
    </div>);
}
```

and the galleryGrid function:

```
galleryGrid () {
  const rows = [];
  // Generate the columns for thumbnails
  const thumbs = this.state.files.map((file) => {
      return (
          <div key={file.name} className="col-sm-4">
              <figure className= "gallery-thumb">
                  <img src={file.preview} alt="thumb" className="ro-imgPreview" />
                  <span className="icon icon-delete"><i className="fa fa-trash"></i></span>
              </figure>
          </div>
      )
  });
  // Push a new row for every set of three thumbnails
  for(let row = 0; row < Math.ceil(this.state.files.length / 3); row += 1){
    rows.push(<div key={ `row-${row}` } className="row">
      {
        thumbs.slice(row * 3, 3);
      }
    </div>); 
  };
  // give back an array of our rows composed of columns
  return rows;
}
```

This will wrap a 'row' div around each set of 3 column divs.

Comment: It is nice approach but i tried and didnt worked for me, i get only one row om images, even if I am uploading more than 3,

Comment: I think the outer div has to have the CSS class 'container', see if this edit works

Comment: Nope, thats doesn't fix the issue.

Comment: Any errors in the browser console? Can you see the generated HTML structure and does it look correct, and have the CSS class names? Also, a very simple thing, have you imported the bootstrap CSS? (see https://react-bootstrap.github.io/getting-started.html under 'Stylesheets')

Comment: Yes I have imported bootstrap and I dont get any errors on borwser, also the html element is correct, but its shows only one row with condition. for example if the (row%3 === 0) then there is no row at all, but if (row % 3 != 0) then the row is shown.

Comment: The for loop iteration was incorrect, try this. If this isn't working, then I don't think I'm able to help... :'(